# Google map Cluster with Url

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer, android-glide

I work with Google Map cluster using Android-map-utils library from google. In my case, I use Glide to load image from URL:

```
@Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(final FeedsModel feedsModel, final MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            // Draw a single person.
            // Set the info window to show their name.
            Glide
                    .with(mActivity.getApplicationContext())
                    .load(feedsModel.getImages().getThumbnail().getUrl())
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
                            mImageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                            Bitmap icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
                            Marker markerToChange = null;
                            for (Marker marker : mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers()) {
                                if (marker.getPosition().equals(feedsModel.getPosition())) {
                                    markerToChange = marker;
                                }
                            }
                            // if found - change icon
                            if (markerToChange != null) {
                                markerToChange.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bitmap icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(final Cluster<FeedsModel> cluster, final MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            // Draw multiple people.
            // Note: this method runs on the UI thread. Don't spend too much time in here (like in this example).
            final List<Drawable> profilePhotos = new ArrayList<Drawable>(Math.min(4, cluster.getSize()));
            final int width = mDimension;
            final int height = mDimension;

            int i = 0;

            for (final FeedsModel p : cluster.getItems()) {
                // Draw 4 at most.
                i++;
                Glide
                        .with(mActivity.getApplicationContext())
                        .load(p.getImages().getThumbnail().getUrl())
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
                                resource.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
                                profilePhotos.add(resource);
                                MultiDrawable multiDrawable = new MultiDrawable(profilePhotos);
                                multiDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

                                mClusterImageView.setImageDrawable(multiDrawable);
                                Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
                                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
                            }
                        });

                if (i == 4) break;
            }
            Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
        }
```

With above code, I see that: image load in Item and Cluster wrong when zoom in or zoom out. What is my wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found solution, I combine with :

```
protected void onClusterItemRendered(FeedsModel clusterItem, Marker marker) 
protected void onClusterRendered(Cluster<FeedsModel> cluster, Marker marker)
```

these function to load image from URL

Comment: Could you share the details method please for this issue ?

Comment: can you please provide a code snippet because it is working for me but when I Zoom in or zoom out in map Images will change.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(Trace trace, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    // Draw a single person.
    // Set the info window to show their name.

    mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.aa001); //temp image.
    icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));

}
@Override
protected void onClusterItemRendered(final Trace trace, final Marker marker){

    Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext())
            .load(ApplicationClass.photoServer + trace.image)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .thumbnail(0.1f)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
                    mImageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                    icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
                    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
                }
            });
}
```

And for the clusters:

```
  @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<Trace> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        super.onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster, markerOptions);
        //pick the first media

        Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterRendered(Cluster<Trace> cluster, Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterRendered(cluster, marker);
        //pick the first trace 
        final Trace trace = cluster.getItems().iterator().next();

        Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext())
                .load(ApplicationClass.photoServer + trace.image)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
                        mClusterImageView. setImageDrawable(resource);
                        Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
                        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution i found with help of above mentions solution

```
private class PersonRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<Person> {
    private final IconGenerator mIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    private final IconGenerator mClusterIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    private final ImageView mImageView;
    private final ImageView mClusterImageView;
    private final int mDimension;
    Bitmap icon;

    public PersonRenderer() {
        super(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mMap, mClusterManager);

        View multiProfile = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.multi_profile, null);
        mClusterIconGenerator.setContentView(multiProfile);
        mClusterImageView = (ImageView) multiProfile.findViewById(R.id.image);

        mImageView = new ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mDimension = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_profile_image);
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(mDimension, mDimension));
        int padding = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_profile_padding);
        mImageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        mIconGenerator.setContentView(mImageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(Person person, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)).title(person.name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(Person clusterItem, final Marker marker) {
        Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(clusterItem.profilePhoto)
                .apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
                .thumbnail(0.1f)
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Drawable drawable, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                        mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                        icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
                        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterRendered(final Cluster<Person> cluster, final Marker marker) {
        final List<Drawable> profilePhotos = new ArrayList<>(Math.min(4, cluster.getSize()));
        final int width = mDimension;
        final int height = mDimension;
        Bitmap dummyBitmap = null;
        Drawable drawable;
        final int clusterSize = cluster.getSize();
        final int[] count = {0};

        for (Person p : cluster.getItems()) {
            // Draw 4 at most.
            if (profilePhotos.size() == 4) break;
            try {
                Glide.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                        .load(p.profilePhoto)
                        .apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
                        .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>(){
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                                resource.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
                                profilePhotos.add(resource);
                                MultiDrawable multiDrawable = new MultiDrawable(profilePhotos);
                                multiDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

                                mClusterImageView.setImageDrawable(multiDrawable);
                                Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
                                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
                            }
                        });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Bitmap icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()));
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(final Cluster<Person> cluster, final MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster) {
        // Always render clusters.
        return cluster.getSize() > 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide the marker in `onBeforeClusterRendered`. You do this so that the marker icon doesn't flicker between the default icon and your custom icon.

In `onClusterItemRendered` fetch the icon bitmap, once it is loaded set it as the marker icon and make the marker visible. If bitmap request fails just show the default icon.

Use Picasso for caching.

```
    final String url = "...";
    clusterManager.setRenderer(new DefaultClusterRenderer<MapClusterItem>(activity, googleMap, clusterManager) {

        @Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MapClusterItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            markerOptions.visible(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onClusterItemRendered(final MapClusterItem clusterItem, final Marker marker) {

            Picasso.
                    with(context).
                    load(url)
                    .into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {}
            });
        }
    });
```